# MPMediaPickerController "Unable to open database file"

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmediapickercontroller, mpmediaquery, core-media

One certain occasions, when presenting an MPMediaPickerController on my iOS device, I get no results displayed and logged in the console I find many SQLite errors along with the error "unable to open database file". I've worked in SQLite before and I I know this error usually means the DB file is currently being used in another thread and/or process.

The problem is, the problem is intermittent at best. It doesn't happen all the time, and I'm not sure there's a common theme to whether this will end up happening or not. I'm familiar enough will SQLite to understand the problem, but the actual database query is "blackboxed" so I have little control over it, and I am new to CoreMedia and the MediaPlayer framework. Has anyone seen this happen before, and if so, did they manage to find a solution to the problem?

**Edit:** The code I use to instantiate the controller is this:

```
MPMediaPickerController* pickCont = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
pickCont.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
pickCont.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
pickCont.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
pickCont.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:pickCont animated:YES];
```

Comment: What are you trying to access?

Comment: I added the code I used to instantiate the controller. I'm just trying to get audio only.

Comment: It's possible that you're trying to access the same files that the OS is using. Try doing a try/catch block and waiting a second before trying again.

Comment: That is actually exactly the problem. The thing is, Objective C is built around the idea of not having to try/catch, because try/catch can be really expensive. My question is, I guess, under what circumstances does the system retain ownership of the DB, thus blocking access or other applications. If I can tell when the requirements are met, I can avoid having to try catch all together.

Comment: I don't think you can tell if the system is using the DB any way aside from trying to use it yourself. If you don't want to do a try-catch then init your controller and check to see if it has anything in it before you present it. If it doesn't, init it again. It might also be helpful to use a narrower media type - I don't know what you need but you could try `MPMediaTypeMusic`. The less types you're trying to access the less likely a conflict is.

Comment: I get the same issue (iPhone 3GS).  Switching the device off and on again seems to resolve it, which implies that it may be something else locking the database